# Event tracking in cordova application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on an android cordova application. I don't have any idea to implement Event tracking for google analytics in my app. Please help me.

Comment: Did you Google for [Google Analytics cordova](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Analytics+cordova)? It should show you some [plugins](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) to start. Does any of them work for you? If not, why?

Comment: I am using danwilson/google-analytics-plugin but how can i implement click event tracking with this please suggest how can i use this

Answer (score 1):

This way works:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY');
});

$(document).on("pageshow", "#examplePage", function(event) {
    window.analytics.trackView('Example Page Screen Title');
});
```

I hope this helps you!